# How do I connect to a Cassandra VM

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cassandra

The following code works if Cassandra and the code are on the same machine:

```
using System;
using Cassandra;

namespace CassandraInsertTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
            .AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
            .Build();

            var session = cluster.Connect("test_keyspace");

            session.Execute("INSERT INTO test_table (id, col1, col2) VALUES (1, 'data1', 'data2')");

            Console.WriteLine($"Finished");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming a username and password is needed if the code is on one machine and cassandra is on a different machine (different ip address)?  So I have tried:

```
        var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
        .AddContactPoint("192.168.0.18") <- the ip address for the cassandra node
        .WithPort(9042)
        .WithCredentials("username to log into the cassandra node","password to log into the cassandra node")
        .Build();
```

I get the following error message:

```
userone@desktop:~/Desktop/vsc$ dotnet run
Unhandled exception. Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts tried for query failed (tried 192.168.0.18:9042: SocketException 'Connection refused')
   at Cassandra.Connections.ControlConnection.Connect(Boolean isInitializing)
   at Cassandra.Connections.ControlConnection.InitAsync()
   at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToCompleteAsync(Task task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Cluster.Cassandra.SessionManagement.IInternalCluster.OnInitializeAsync()
   at Cassandra.ClusterLifecycleManager.InitializeAsync()
   at Cassandra.Cluster.Cassandra.SessionManagement.IInternalCluster.ConnectAsync[TSession](ISessionFactory`1 sessionFactory, String keyspace)
   at Cassandra.Cluster.ConnectAsync(String keyspace)
   at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete(Task task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete[T](Task`1 task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Cluster.Connect(String keyspace)
   at HelloWorld.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/userone/Desktop/vsc/Program.cs:line 17
userone@desktop:~/Desktop/vsc$
```

The iptables on the node (the cassandra server) is currently set as follows:

```
node1@node1:~$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A IMPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.73/32 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 7000,7001,7199,9042,9160,9142 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
node1@node1:~$
```

Note 1: Both the machine with the app and the machine with cassandra installed can be pinged and tracerouted in both directions.

Note 2: I have tested the username and password and can log into the cassandra server without any issues when tried directly on the server.

Note 3: Cassandra is running in a VM which I just created today.  The VM is a guest machine on the host machine which runs the code.

Note 4: Both the Host OS and Guest OS are Linux.

Comment: The looback address 127.0.0.1 will only work on the same machine.  You have to use the remote machine IP address or Name for a remote machine.

Comment: @jdweng I've used 192.168.0.18 which I get from the remote machine when I check ifconfig.  Still get the connection refused message.

Comment: What port are you using?  On remote machine from cmd.exe >Netstat -a check if port is listening.  Try from cmd.exe >Ping 192.168.0.18  Also try machine name instead of IP.

Comment: You need to check whether port 9042 is open from your source server to destination or your services running properly?

Comment: @LetsNoSQL, please see current iptables results from the cassandra node/server.

Comment: You might need to set a static ip on the host machine and enable port forwarding. Just a thought

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
```

If that works from the same machine, then you probably have Cassandra *bound* to that IP.  If you need to connect to your node(s) remotely, then you need to bind a routeable IP to that node.

Run a `nodetool status`.  If you see your cluster status showing your node with an IP of 127.0.0.1, then connecting *to* the local machine *from* the local machine is the only scenario that will *ever* work.

Try running the following command on your node:

```
grep _address cassandra.yaml
```

The IP address returned in the output is the only one that an application is allowed to connect to.  If you want to be able to connect to 192.168.0.18, then the `listen` and `rpc` addresses should look something like this:

```
listen_address: 192.168.0.18
rpc_address: 192.168.0.18
```

Note that you'll need to change your `seeds` list, too.

Also, if you're on a VM/provider that has both internal and external IP addresses, then you'll also need to set your `broadcast_` addresses to the external IP:

```
broadcast_address: 10.6.5.5
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.6.5.5
listen_address: 192.168.0.18
rpc_address: 192.168.0.18
```

But try setting just `listen` and `rpc` to 192.168.0.18 first.

**Edit 20191022**

> Just wanted to double check, do I add 192.168.0.18 as the listen_address and rpc_address to the cassandra node where the cassandra node has the ip address 192.168.0.18?

Yes.  Also make sure that your node's seed list is set like this:

```
- seeds: "192.168.0.18"
```

> Before I did that, the value of the listen_address and rpc_address were set to localhost

I thought so.

> However, after making the changes you suggested, nodetool status now gives me

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:7199 - connection refused
```

Ironically, that's the same message nodetool returns when Cassandra is not running.  At this point I would check the system log and see if it is returning errors that may be preventing it from starting.  I suspect that the seed list still reads "127.0.0.1".

**tl;dr;**

If you intend to connect to your cluster/node remotely, then you *cannot* use the default configurations which bind Cassandra to the home IP (127.0.0.1/localhost).  And that includes all `_address` settings, as well as your `seeds` list.

Comment: I've made the `listen_address` and `rpc_address` changes only as I don't think the VM has both internal and external IP addresses, then restarted cassandra.  But the changes did not seem to work.  I still get a `connection refused` message when I try to use the app or even `telnet 192.168.0.18 9042`.

Comment: Just wanted to double check, do I add `192.168.0.18` as the `listen_address` and `rpc_address` to the cassandra node where the cassandra node has the ip address `192.168.0.18`?

Comment: Before I did that, the value of the `listen_address` and `rpc_address` were set to `localhost`.  The value of `nodetool status` was originally set to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: However, after making the changes you suggested, `nodetool status` now gives me `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:7199 - connection refused`

Comment: @oshirowanen Edit made.

Comment: I will give the updates a try asap.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: You were right, it was the seed which was missing.  Thanks for the help and sorry for the delay in replying.

Comment: @oshirowanen No worries on the delay.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using something like `telnet 192.168.0.18 9042` to test whether the network is properly configured for this scenario. The error that the driver is throwing is just a standard socket error that is returned when the driver can't connect to the cassandra host.

Comment: I get the message: 'telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused'

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any experience with Cassandra, but almost all of my connectivity problems were related to firewalls' configuration, OS distributed and network services, etc.
 So, if everything works well locally, do not change anything in source code before you are entirely sure about it.
 I suggest to check the following list first:

- Check all servers' firewall configuration
- Check if all needed services are run in all servers (search if Cassandra is depended on any services).
- Check the network firewall and subnet port and protocol access limitation if exist.
- Check if Cassandra is fully and functionally up and works on port 9042.